# Showing All Messages Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.0'

Tags: ios, xcode

For the first time to use Xcode I want to real machine debugging when there is a problem.

Look at the pictures:

[image]

I could not find any general, only basic, customized, all, combined and levels.

Comment: Can you please post more information on the Build settings and Provisioning in your Xcode?

Comment: @Prav ok,Xcode8.0,Code signing identity are all iOS Developer

Comment: Are you using COCOAPODS?

Answer (score 0):

Under the project settings, General tab, "Signing" section, check "Automatically manage signing" and select "Personal Team" for the "Team" setting. You need to be logged in with any valid Apple ID. (Check under Xcode menu -> "Preferences..." menu item -> "Accounts" tab and make sure at least one Apple ID appears there.)

This will let you install any App on your own hardwired devices that will be valid for about a week, with no membership fees to Apple.